# Rotating a set of images

Tags: image, rotation

I am trying to setup a "rotating image" for part of a site I am working on. I have taken many photos of a single item (30+), and I want to display them like it is a rotating 3D image (with a possible draggable speed).

One approach I have taken is setting it as a CSS background, and looping through the images every 0.1s. It works alright, but it flickers like crazy until the image has done a full rotation (I am assuming this is because the image is not yet cached)

Has anyone implemented something similar or have a suggestion?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Cycle is an amazingly versatile, light-weight, jQuery plugin.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/